# Google Sheets select error: =SUM(QUERY(A:D, "SELECT A WHERE ISDATE(A) = TRUE", 1))

Tags: google-sheets

What's wrong with this formula?

=SUM(QUERY(A:D, "SELECT A WHERE ISDATE(A) = TRUE", 1))

I'm trying to only sum column D values when column A contains a date. Seems straight forward but I'm getting "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2" Column A could either be blank, have alphanumeric values or have a date value.

=SUM(QUERY(A:D, "SELECT A WHERE ISDATE(A) = TRUE", 1))

Comment: you cannot use google sheets functions *inside* a query string like that.

it seems unlikely you are trying to add up dates anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly use the values of `ISDATE()` for 2 reasons.

1. The `ISDATE()` formula doesn't work with arrays, so even if you concatenate the `Query` formula with `ISDATE()` it will return an error. For example, if you use the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISDATE(A2:A))
```

It will only return 1 value, not an array like this:

[image: test 1]

When use in the `Query`, formula:

```
=QUERY(A1:D14, "Select A where" & ARRAYFORMULA(ISDATE(A2:A)) & "=TRUE")
```

You will get the error message:
[image: test2]

2. The second reason is the one mentioned by @MattKing, Google Sheet will not calculate the value for this formula.

While doing some test, I found a workaround for you. I have my data arrange like this for the test:

[image: data]

I found 2 formulas that accomplish what you need:

The first formula, is using the formula `ISDATE_STRICT()` which for some odd reason is not inside the Google Documentation, by converting the table + the Array created with the `ISDATE_STRICT()` formula to a new array for the `Query`, like this:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(QUERY(
        {A:D, ARRAYFORMULA(ISDATE_STRICT(A:A))}, 
        "Select Col4 where Col5=TRUE"))))
```

[image: test 3]

And the second formula, is using `LAMBDA` and `ByRow` to create the new array.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(QUERY(
         {A:D, BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(r,ISDATE(r)))},
         "Select Col4 where Col5=TRUE"))))
```

[image: test 4]

**Reference:**

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276)
- [BYROW function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)
- [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D:D,ISDATE(A:A)))
```